# Which other Schengen countries should I visit from Munich such that the cost is minimal?

Tags: budget, europe, schengen, recommendations

I will visit Munich for a business trip. I have purchased around trip flight tickets from my home country to Munich. I have a week for doing nothing so I want to visit one or more other countries in Schengen area but I want to minimize the cost. Transportation cost should be not more than around 100 euros.

Which countries can I visit?

Comment: "Schengen" in the question is superfluous, as there are no non-Schengen countries nearby.

Comment: but what is "minimal cost" for you? going to Denmark from Munich is probably the same cost as going to Munich from home for me!

Comment: @vartec: To make it clearer and avoid responding unnecessary comments for sure.

Comment: @Vince: Transportation cost is not more than around 100 euros in total.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Austria** is pretty close. Salzburg is +- 2 hours by [train](http://www.bahn.de/p/view/index.shtml) and a single ticket costs 22 EUR. Vienna is also within reach. It's 6 hours by bus. With [Orangeways](http://orangeways.com/) you can find single tickets for as low as 16 EUR.

You can also consider a trip to the **Czech Republic**. Prague is a bit less than 6 hours by [direct train](http://www.alex.info/) from Munich. A return ticket costs 65 EUR. You can also go there by bus. There are several providers. It may be a bit cheaper, depending on when you book and travel. Travel time by bus will be around 5 hours.

**Switzerland** can be an option too. It is more or less 4 hours you can go by bus from Munich to Zurich. Prices with [MeinFernbus.de](http://meinfernbus.de/) start at 15 EUR, depending on when you book and when you travel.

Comment: It will be the first time for me visiting other Schengen countries. My question: Is there an immigration gate, in which  immigration procedure will be redone, when leaving and entering the border between 2 adjacent Schengen countries?

Comment: No, there are no more systematic checks. In many cases you will hardly notice that you are crossing a border. However, in times of populist pressure and generalised paranoia, even in Europe, there can be more or less sporadic controls. But then they will only check if your documents are ok.

Comment: OK. Thank you. I am waiting for other better answers (if any) before pressing the green check mark button.

Comment: Czech Republic would be a great option if you want to keep costs low. Zurich, for example, might be easy to travel to, but the cost of staying there would be quite higher.

Comment: München - Wien is 4 hours by train, I would not travel that route by bus...

Comment: Thanks so much @Marcel C. for the link for meinfernbus, I just needed something like that right now. I agree with previous comment that Switzerland will be expensive, I live here so I should know. However, if you go to Austria, you can take a bus from there (https://westbus.at/en) to Prague, Bratislava, Budapest, all of them cheaper options.

Comment: @KristvanBesien You are right. I have not indicated the train as he wants to minimize the transport cost. And bus will be significantly cheaper than train.

Comment: @fluffy As fas as I know, Westbus does not go to Munich. Or am I wrong?